# Using COUNTIFS to get rolling count

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, counting, countif

I've been working on this most of the day and I'm stumped on this one part.

Here's some background: I've been asked to an injury log (which is created in Excel) and create a report around it (which I've been told has to be in Excel). Right now, I'm trying to count the number of injuries, that meet certain conditions, within the last three months.

This is what I got working so far:

```
=COUNTIFS('All Injuries'!C:C,"*S/R*",'All Injuries'!K:K,"*Yes*",'All Injuries'!M:M,">="&TODAY()-180,'All Injuries'!M:M,"<="&TODAY())
```

The issue that I'm running into is I can't depend on the TODAY function. There's a cell - A2 - that will have a date in it (12/15/2015, 11/15/2015, 10/15/2015, etc.)

What I want is to count the number of injuries that fall within that range (A2 to A2 minues 180 days). However, when I replace &TODAY, with A2, the formula just errors out.

So, that's where I'm stuck.

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the actual formula that gives you an error.

Comment: Even you see a date in A1 it's probably stored as text. Either enter date there according to your pc's date format, either use `=DATE(2015,10,15)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace

`&TODAY`

with

`&A2`

Comment: replace `&TODAY()` with `&A2`  dont't forget to get rid of the `()`.